# How to run the dos2unix command on files inside multiple folders and sub-folders?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command, dos2unix

I want to run the `dos2unix` command on all files inside a folder. The issue here is the folder contains files and sub-folders. The sub-folder again contains files and folders. So if I simply run `user/bin/dos2unix <folder>`, it will throw an error since there are sub-folders and folders present in the main folder.

Any idea on how I can bypass this so that the `dos2unix` command would run on the files inside each of the folders?

Comment: what have you tried? have your tried a: 
`for i in \`find -type f .\``  
command

Answer (score 4):

just run the below command from where you want to execute your dos2unix command. Change the below `"*.txt"` as per your file extension type. If they are different in different directory location then make it `"*.*"`

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs dos2unix
```

Here `.` is your current directory and `"*.txt" are all your`dos` files.

How will the above command  work? It will find all the `dos` files `*.txt` and input each `file` as parameter to `dos2unix` command and which will convert that `dos` format file to `unix` format.

If you want to run it from any location just provide full path in place of `.` like below:-

```
find /path/from/where/you/want/to -name "*.txt" | xargs dos2unix
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find <folder> -type f | xargs dos2unix
```

**Explanation:**

- `find <folder> -type f` will list all the regular files inside `<folder>` and its sub-folders
- `xargs dos2unix` will apply the `dos2unix` command to each of the files found by `find`

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` isn't needed here; just use the `-exec` primary to `find`:

```
find -type f -exec dos2unix {} +
```